# What are AWS requirements for Senior Software Engineers?

Tags: software-industry, job-search, software-development, skills

I'm seeing a lot of senior engineer jobs that require Amazon Web Services (AWS) experience in addition to software development experience. Can anyone expand on what this means? Does it refer to working with AWS instances, creating servers etc. or is there a deeper software development link to AWS via API's that I'm possibly unaware of.

[edit] No it isn't company specific. A quick scan of this mornings listings on jobserve.com showed AWS as a requirement in 5 out of 10 'Senior Software Engineer' jobs. This question cannot be answered by inquiring with the company because job postings are handled by recruiters who aren't going to be able to answer the question. One recruiter told me that a customer was posting a job for 5 years of Kubernetes requirement in 2016, something that wasn't possible but it was requested nevertheless. I suspect AWS is being slapped on the list by hiring managers and this is why I asked the question here, to try and validate the requirement. So no, it isn't off topic.

Comment: This is company specific, we have no way of knowing.

Comment: A good way to answer questions like this is to find a trustworthy recruiter in your location who specializes in your specific field (i.e. software engineers) - then ask them what companies are typically looking for with regards to X.

Comment: What is AWS? Please explain

Answer (score 4):

> I'm seeing a lot of senior engineer jobs that require AWS experience in addition to software development experience. Can anyone expand on what this means? Does it refer to working with AWS instances, creating servers etc.

Although this is job-specific, **yes**, that is basically what they are expecting from possible candidates.

Besides knowing how to code, jobs that ask for AWS experience are looking for candidates that have hands-on experience with AWS services and products (servers, RDS, EC2, Lambdas, etc.).

Still, this will really depend on each specific job and company and what *they* really want in a candidate, but broadly "AWS experience" is what described before.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to say exactly the scope but I would imagine the very least would be integrating AWS with a CI/CD tool like Jenkins. I would imagine the very least knowing what CI/CD is but not necessarily AWS. Also there's the whole aspect of configuring the AWS for DBs and things like that.

I would imagine you'd need to talk to the job about exactly what they mean by the generic term AWS. I would say it's better to explain your skills with AWS rather than worry about what you think they want to hear. That way you go in able to explain what you know and they'd know without you stumbling to figure out things.

Comment: On the other side, it would be *great* if the job post were more explicit: *"Experience with AWS EC2 as well as integration with Jenkins"*... that way the reader will know exactly what they seek (if the vague AWS experience term is used I suspect that not even they know what they really want a candidate to know, tho)

Comment: I agree but regardless of what *they* want, the truth is what you must know. They want *something* with AWS so you can say, *"Hey I have experience of X, Y, and Z of AWS."* They might say, *"That's great. We were looking to train up someone to know X, Y, and Z of AWS but since you know, you're a great hire and we want to get you in here asap."*

Comment: Agreed. If the requirements are unclear then OP should do their best exposing what they know about AWS

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Web Services actually offers more than [150](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Web_Services) services and tools in 2019. It is unreasonable to expect a developer to know all services in detail – especially not the new very domain-specific services.

But there are a couple of services that have been around for quite a while and that are the base of every infrastructure: EC2, RDS, S3, elastic load balancers, elastic IPs. I would expect that a senior engineer knows them all and has used them via GUI and CLI. They should be able to describe the use-cases, how pricing works, disadvantages, etc.

Furthermore, I would expect a senior engineer to understand security-related topics and tools on AWS: IAM, roles, policies, VPC. And I would expect that they know how to organizes and manage AWS infrastructure as code.

Apart from the basics it highly depends on the company and its needs. They might be interested in big data, search engines or machine learning. I would not expect that someone who just said they had AWS experience without going into details that they had any knowledge in these services.